# Какая функция для того чтобы записать текст в буфер обмена

Tags: c++

Собственно все в заголовке
"Какая функция для того чтобы записать текст в буфер обмена"  В C++

Comment: Какая библиотека или ОС?

Comment: В самом языке C++ и в стандартной библиотеке таких функций нет. Нужно использовать сторонние библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Пример записи и чтения текста в буфер обмена для ОС Windows. ([Подробнее](http://netcode.ru/cpp/?artID=248&katID=3&lang&skatID=22))

```
CString source; //в эту переменную нужно записать текст, который в дальнейшем поместится в буфер обмена
//запись текста в буфер обмена
if(OpenClipboard())//открываем буфер обмена
{
   HGLOBAL hgBuffer;
   char* chBuffer;
   EmptyClipboard(); //очищаем буфер
   hgBuffer= GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, source.GetLength()+1);//выделяем память
   chBuffer= (char*)GlobalLock(hgBuffer); //блокируем память
   strcpy(chBuffer, LPCSTR(source));
   GlobalUnlock(hgBuffer);//разблокируем память
   SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hgBuffer);//помещаем текст в буфер обмена
   CloseClipboard(); //закрываем буфер обмена
}

//чтение текста из буфера обмена
CString fromClipboard;//в эту переменную сохраним текст из буфера обмена
if ( OpenClipboard() )//открываем буфер обмена
{
   HANDLE hData = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);//извлекаем текст из буфера обмена
   char* chBuffer= (char*)GlobalLock(hData);//блокируем память
   fromClipboard = chBuffer;
   GlobalUnlock(hData);//разблокируем память
   CloseClipboard();//закрываем буфер обмена
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в ответ, что это способ для Windows.